# I am trying to make the game tron in java, but the light trail behind the bike is not updating after the initial location of the bike

Tags: java, arrays

So as the title states, I am trying to make the game tron for a programming final project. Everything works except for one crucial part, The light trail. I have a class for the light trail that takes the `x` and `y` locations of the player from a different class and draws a blue square in the players position. When I run and compile the program a square is drawn in the players starting position once the player is moved. However, the square does not draw again after the players first move.

Here is my trail class

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class pTrail {

    player p;
    int x;
    int y;
    int c;
    Rectangle pT;

    public pTrail() {
        p = new player();
        x = p.getX();
        y = p.getY();
        pT = new Rectangle (x,y);
    }

    public Rectangle getRect() {
        return pT;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g, Graphics2D g2) {
        g2.setColor(Color.blue);
        g2.fillRect(x,y,10,10);
    }
}
```

`int c` is designed to later be a variable to change the color of the trail.
If you need more code then please comment what you need to see, driver, player etc.

Comment: Not enough code to give a precise answer, but you're only altering `x` and `y` in the constructor, so you're probably piling up rectangles in the same location.

Comment: Indenting! Use it! Also, note that class names in Java should always start with a capital letter (i.e. be in TitleCase, not camelCase)

Answer (score 1):

You need to take player as a parameter in `pTrail()`. Right now you are making a new player inside of `pTrail()` but it need to be like this `pTrail(player p)`. The reason your rectangles aren't following your player is because they are always created in the default location for player. If you instead pass the player as a parameter the trail will actually have the player's position.

Answer (score 0):

There is missing code, but maybe this will help:
Because you say that everything is working i believe that when your player move you update x or\and y (if not, do it).
Now you need to run the draw method again with the right x and y values (and so on in any move of the player).